# Get google map when click on an address

Tags: php, google-maps-markers

I want to place google map in my PHP project.. Is it possible to get google map while click on an addresss?? My requirement is "when clicking on the address it will open in maps" Is it possible in PHP?? Anybody please help..

Comment: You need some logic to detect addresses from strings first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have an address written like "10 Downing Street", you can pass that as a search query to Google Maps.

For example http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=10%20downing%20street

It will help if you also give it more information - like a country.  There are thousands of "Downing Streets" around the world - so if you want the one just in Canada, you would say http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=10%20downing%20street,%20canada

The more information you have (State, Post Code / Zip, etc) the more accurate the map will be.

Comment: Thank u so much... Is it possible to show this page in a popup?? Suppose the code is like <a href='http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=$b4g0x2[3]'>$b4g0x2[3]</a>.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. Visit google maps and search for a link to the specified Location and add this to your code. If you want to make it dynamic look at the syntax from the Link and generate your own.

example:https://www.google.de/maps?q=London,+United+Kingdom&hl=en&sll=51.093173,0.271912&sspn=1.430024,3.56781&t=h&geocode=FYfwEQMdPQ3-_w&hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&z=11

there are basically 2 Numbers (coordinates) you want to edit (and the search request).

Answer (score 0):

the solution which has been provided works fine in iOS 5.1.1 - when user clicks on http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=10%20downing%20street it opens Google Map Native App from iPhone, but when I try the same URL in iPhone iOS 6.0 - it opens maps.google.co.uk website.

Do we have anyway to open Apple's Native Map app?